# Eigenvector with complex numbers

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I basically tried to calculate the eigenvectors of the given matrice just like I did it with the first matrice with real numbers. But now with complex numbers my calculation is kind of going nowwhere and my answers don't match with those from WolframAlpha. Is my method the right way or am I doing it completly wrong?

[image: screenshot of my work]

Comment: Please show your work so people can say what is right or wrong.

Comment: You might also explain what you mean when you say that your answers don’t match those from W|A. Students often forget that eigenvectors are _not_ unique.

Comment: The matrix $C$ is triangular so the eigenvalues are the diagonal.

Comment: @Shogun I don’t think that the OP has even gotten to $C$ yet. The issue isn’t computing the eigenvalues; it’s finding associated eigenvectors.

Comment: It looks like you’re getting lost when trying to row-reduce $B-(3+i)I$. The process is no different than it is with real numbers; the necessary multiplications and divisions just take more work.

Comment: Here is one mistake I noticed: $\lambda^{2}-b\lambda+c=0$ has roots $(b\pm \sqrt {b^{2}-4c}) /2$ not $(b/2 \pm \sqrt {(b/2)^{2}-4c} )/2$.

Comment: The $4$ looks like a $9$ and that threw me off. Also, I can't read german cursive.

Answer (score 1):

Few things which may help you to ease out your calculations:

-Characteristic equation for a square matrix of order $3$ is $t^3-tr(A)t^2+(\sum_1^3 A_{ii})t-det(A)=0$ where $tr(A)=$sum of diagonal entries of $A$ and $A_{ii}=$ cofactor of element $a_{ii}$.

-To find roots of a cubic equation $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$, we seek an integer which divide $c$ and is a zero of $f(x)$. If we are lucky enough (if integer roots occur) and $p$ be such number then $x=p$ is first root. Then if complex roots occur they must occur in pairs. Let $r\pm i s$ be the complex conjugates which are roots of equation.

Use $p+r\pm is= -a$ to get $r$ and then $p.(r\pm is)=-c$ to get $s$.